# repeating task in android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

i want to do repeating task on specific time of every day so i have something like this on my `Main Activity`:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent doServiceIntent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, doServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    else
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and my service class is something like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

but it is not exact

what is the problem? how can i solve it?

Comment: "What is the problem?" is a question I'm having too when reading your question. Can you explain what "it is not exact" means? What do you expect to happen and what is happening instead? Also note from the official docs, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent) : "The alarm will be delivered as nearly as possible to the requested trigger time."

Comment: thank you, i want to be really exact what should i do?how android clock alarms is exact?